# Clique problem for regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

I am looking for NP complete results for cliques in regular graphs. For example is the general problem of determining if a regular graph on n vertices has an n/2 clique NP-complete? (obviously the question is interesting only if the degree is at least n/2). You could also ask the same question for say regular graphs of degree 3n/4.

Comment: There is lots of information (though not an answer to your exact question) at en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem.

Answer (score 5):

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a graph and $c ≤ |V |$ a positive integer. The independent sets of $G$ are precisely the cliques of the complementary graph $\overline{G}$.

INDEPENDENT SET

INSTANCE: Graph $G=(V,E)$, positive integer $c$.

QUESTION: Does $G$ contain an independent set of size $c$ or more,

The independent set problem remains NP-complete when restricted to
3-regular planar graphs.

Reference:

COMPUTERS AND Intractability, A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness

Michael R. Garey / David S. Johnson

page 194-195

Comment: This answers the question for cliques of specified size, but it doesn't answer it for cliques of size n/2. 3-regular graphs have an independent set of size $n/2$ iff they are bipartite.

Comment: The key is that the complement of a regular graph is regular.